# Get nested node value with SimpleXMLParser

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a simple XML response I'm receiving into a variable ($response):

```
<tsresponse xmlns="http://tableau.com/api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemalocation="http://tableau.com/api http://tableau.com/api/ts-api-3.7.xsd">
   <pagination pagenumber="1" pagesize="100" totalavailable="1">
      <users>
         <user externalauthuserid="" id="abcd1234-hijk-lmno-1234-abcd9876" name="TestUsername" siterole="Explorer">
         </user>
      </users>
   </pagination>
</tsresponse>
```

I am trying to retrieve the value of "id".

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($response) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
            
$tableauuserid = $xml->pagination->users[0]->user['id'];
echo "The (existing) Tableau User ID is: ". $tableauuserid;
```

The (mostly) same format works for a level up where I'm retrieving the value of id in a similar response - except then I'm just dealing with "user" and not "pagination->users->user".  Currently the variable $tableauuserid is empty.

Any ideas on how I can retrieve the value of id?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, getting `The (existing) Tableau User ID is: abcd1234-hijk-lmno-1234-abcd9876` with that exact same code

Comment: @kerbh0lz, seems to run OK for me.

Comment: @NigelRen Nice, that makes us two then ;)

Comment: How do you set `$response`? Here's working code: https://3v4l.org/KiRWM

Comment: Good to know something is working for others... hah! I set $response as the result of a curl_exec call. ```$response = curl_exec($curl);```. I'm using the same method twice in the code that comes before this, so I'm a little stumped. When I echo out $response it looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to find any `<user>` element would be to use XPath.  The only slight complication is the default namespace defined on the base element.  To get round this you need to register that namespace (using `registerXPathNamespace()`) and then use the prefix as part of the name.

Calling `xpath()` will return a list of matching nodes, so you need to use `[0]` to use the first one...

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace("d", "http://tableau.com/api");
$user = $xml->xpath("//d:user[@id]");
$tableauuserid = $user[0]['id'];
```

Comment: This works great, though I must admit I'm not familiar with the method. Are there any other things I need to be aware of with registerXPathNamespace? Does it only persist for the period the function is being run, for example?

Comment: `registerXPathNamespace()` only exists for the node that you register it with, so if you then query from `$tableauuserid`, you would need to do it again.  One other thing is that the result of`$tableauuserid` is an instance of SimpleXMLElement, so if you do certain operations on it (like using it as an index) you need to convert it to a string `(string)$tableauuserid`.

Comment: That preemptively answered a problem I was likely going to face. Thank you very much!